# .NET 6, Identity Server 5, client management

Tags: .net-core, identityserver5

The templates use `appsettings.json` file to configure the client. The `AddClients()` method inside `AddApiAuthorization()` registers an `Enumerable.Empty<Client>` and then goes to add the clients from the appsettings file.

```
builder.AddInMemoryClients(Enumerable.Empty<Client>());
```

Is it possible to change the `Enumerable.Empty<Client>` to `ConcurrentBag<Client>` and add clients at run time?

I am probably not thinking about all this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to add clients to dotnet template generated code.

inject `IOptions<ApiAuthorizationOptions>` and use the `_options.Value.Clients` object to add the client.

This following example should get you started on the right path.

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
props.Add("Profile", "IdentityServerSPA");

clients.Add(new Client
{
    ClientId = "Template",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequireClientSecret = false,

    RedirectUris = { "/authentication/login-callback" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "/authentication/logout-callback" },

    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "TemplateAPI" },

    Properties = props
});
```

Hope this saves some time for you.